# Odds of 6 dice rolls?

Tags: probability

What are the odds of rolling a "3" in a single dice roll:

1/6.

What are the odds of rolling at least one "3" in two seperate dice rolls:

1/6 + 1/6 = 2/6

What are the odds of rolling at least one "3" in six seperate dice rolls:

6/6 = 100% or certain.

Which it certainly isn't.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

--

Update:  Suddenly understood what I did wrong.  The odds I am calculating or of 1x "3" coming up in six throws, or 2x "3" coming up in six throws, or 3x "3" coming up in six throws, etc.

So understandably the odds are cumulative and can therfore go over 100%.

Comment: Addition is not correct here (as is revealed in the third case). The probability that there is at least one 3 equals $1$ minus the probability that no 3 is thrown. So go looking for the probability that no 3 is thrown.

Comment: Nothing, ever, becomes more than 100% likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of rolling no $3$s in $n$ rolls is
$$
\left(\frac56\right)^n
$$
so the probability of rolling at least one $3$ in $n$ rolls is
$$
1-\left(\frac56\right)^n
$$

Comment: Yes I understand that but I thought the Addition rule of probability applied:  "When two events, A and B, are mutually exclusive, the probability that A or B will occur is the sum of the probability of each event."  Why not in this case?

Comment: The event of rolling a $3$ on the first die and rolling a $3$ on the second die is counted twice if you add $\frac16$ and $\frac16$. It gets even worse the more dice you add like that.

Comment: @Karlth Simply because in this case A and B are *not* mutually exclusive. Throwing a 3 in the first round does not exclude throwing a 3 in the second.